# Can Android normal level permissions be requested at installation time (in the manifest)?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-8.0-oreo

In later versions of Android (like 8.0.0), can we still declare *normal level* permissions in the manifest, like INTERNET permission and expect it to be granted at installation time?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

or do we need to explicitly request them through the code?

If the second, do we need to ask for it on every single activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can we still declare normal level permissions in the manifest, like INTERNET permission and expect it to be granted at installation time?

Yes. Only `dangerous` ones need to be requested at runtime.

Comment: Thank you! Does this also mean that normal level permisions can not be revoked latter by user?

Comment: @daneejela: In ordinary Android, you are correct. The user can only revoke `dangerous` permissions, the same ones that they grant at runtime. That way, your code will be able to respond just using the same code that you have for requesting the permissions originally.

Comment: So if I declare INTERNET permission in the manifest and user installs the app - I can be sure that the app has internet permission granted forever?

Comment: @daneejela: Yes. That does not mean that your app has Internet access, as there are lots of reasons why it might not (airplane mode, lousy connectivity, firewall problems, Internet routing problems, ISP problems, etc.).

Comment: Yes, of course. I am asking only for permission grant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can declare normal level permissions in the manifest. But in 6.0 and above you have to check that permission is granted or not by user at runtime.

Comment: Are you sure that they have to be checked if they are granted? Wouldn't that mean that the manifest declaration is useless?

Comment: Yes, We have to declare it in manisfest and as well as have to handle that permission in our app also because user can allow or deny for a particular permission. if user denied for a particular permission and we use functionality regarding that permission then app crashes in that case.

Comment: Soory, since your answer clashes with @CommonsWare's answer, I'm going to trust his reputation this time and accept his answer, but if it proves wrong, I'll accept your answer instead.